# nth-child and nth-of-type includes other divs

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm creating a news section, in which most of the posts are smaller and in pairs - you'll see in the small fiddle I made - while some (depending on their date) are larger and take up the whole width.

My main issue is the large posts seem to be interfering with the borders (which are supposed to be at the top and bottom, with one going down the center.

See example:

http://jsfiddle.net/r9tLh/

****EDIT****

I've also just realised that if there is one small post on its own followed by a large post, the next post will be on the wrong side for the selector to do its correct styling, so even if I fix the nth selectors an error still may occur. Is there any other way I can do this, such as the odd and even selectors starting again after a large post?

```
.blogPost:nth-of-type(odd) {
    border-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}
.blogPost:nth-of-type(even) {
    padding-left: 0;
    border-right: 1px solid #4E4E4E;
}
```

Comment: I was using `nth-of-type` as a test, before that it was simply nth-child, which is evidently still incorrect..

Comment: Sorry, but it's unclear what you are asking.

Comment: @JoshC The post after the second large post has incorrect borders around it, due to the odd and even selectors including the large post.

Comment: All of your elements are `div`s, so `:nth-of-type()` will work identically to `:nth-child()` regardless of class.

Comment: Alright - I finally see the problem.. I changed the selectors to `:nth-child` as @BoltClock mentions, `:nth-of-type` is useless.. however I can't seem to figure it out.. it seems like a glitch/bug.. http://jsfiddle.net/gugrt/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved my current problem by using javascript to grab exclusively by class:

```
$(function() {
$('.blogPost:odd').css({
                'border-left': '0',
                'padding-right': '0'
});
$('.blogPost:even').css({
                'border-right': '1px solid #4E4E4E',
                'padding-left': '0'
});
});
```

However the problem I mentioned above - if there is only one small post before a large post, the following small post will encounter the same problem. I might open a new question for that if I can't solve it.

Thanks for your help making me realise I couldn't do this with just CSS.